# Magento 2 need to upgrade compile and deploy everytime

Tags: magento-2.1

For every change that I do related to database I have to upgrade the code.

On upgrading it when I load the page, Css and Js are not applied.

I tried giving permissions to it as well. Only when I upgrade, compile and deploy and then give permission I can see Css and Js loaded.

I am running it in developer mode. This is time consuming and also tiresome.

Any way I can avoid this?

> FYI: **I have set Admin->Stores->Config->Advanced->Developer->Static
>   Files Settings->Sign Static Files->No**

I had to this because immediately after installation my css and js files were not loading and the only way that worked out was this.

Comment: Is this on the production site or on your own development environment?

Comment: @Paul Development environment

Answer (score 0):

While you are in developer mode you shouldn't compile DI, generation, or the static content as they will be created dynamically when requested.

Delete the var/di, var/generation and the contents of pub/static and you shouldn't have that issue.

When you upgrade a module, simply run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
```

With regards to the static file versions, make sure your Nginx configuration / .htaccess files have the required line included to handle those static content requests.

Apache with .htaccess - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess#L16

Nginx - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample#L123

Comment: Hello paul nginx link is not working